# Multiplying an option value by a fixed value

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Using Excel 2010 I have a form that contains five option buttons in each of nine rows.  Each column, in which an option button can be selected, has a numeric value ranging from 5 -1.  Each row begins with a statement which also has a numeric value, which ranges from 10-1.  When an option button is selected, the value of that column is to be multiplied by the value of the row and the result entered in another column on the form.
Suggestions?
Thank you in advance.
JB

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you have used ActiveX option buttons the following idea should do what you want.

1. Reserve 5 columns on your worksheet. In my test they were the cells H3:M3.
2. Now look for the LinkedCell property of your option buttons. Link No. 1 to H3, No. 2 to I3, No. 3 to J3 (whatever your corresponding columns are, but within the same row as your option buttons). Bear in mind that these are the numbers 1 to 5 which you want to use in multiplications.
3. In the cell where you want the result, enter this formula.

   =MATCH(TRUE,$H3:$M3,0) * $A3

where 3 is the row where your linked option buttons are, and A is the value between 10 and 1 which you indicated you have somewhere.

The formula will create a total by multiplying a value between 1 and 5, depending upon which option button was clicked, with the value in column A. Copy the formulas down as required. Unfortunately, you will have to set the LinkedCell properties individually for each button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to multiple Row number with a cell value, so for this I think no need to create Optionbutton,, simply you can multiple Row number with cell value,, like

C3=Row(A3) *B3, Drag it down.

Comment: Thank you, Your suggestion would work if the values in the row were constant, but the multiplication formula depends on the Optionbutton in that row selected by the user.   If the user selects the Optionbutton in the first column, then the row value (10) is multiplied by 5, if they select the second column, the value is multiplied by 4.  If the third column is selected, the value of 10 is multiplied by 3, if they select the fourth column, the value of 10 is multiplied by 2, and if the last column is selected, the value of 10 is multiplied by 1.  The answer goes in another column.

Comment: I too tried the recommended formula:   "=Match(True, $H3:$M3, 0)*$A3"  and it is not working for me